# Is there a Way to Align Camera to View and Fit the View?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> causes the camera to teleport over and align itself to the current view in the 3D viewport.
However, it usually takes up only a small portion of the view, meaning that you have to move the camera back to fit the same view you had before. Is there a way to set the camera view to fill more of the 3D viewport when using this feature?

Comment: Do you mean that the camera is zoomed further in than you expected or that the camera has a large dark border surrounding it when in camera view?

Comment: Kinda both.  David's answer below does what I was wanting.  The camera zoom can be adjusted to match the viewport zoom by lowering the Focal Length from the Camera tab in the Properties Editor.  My goal was to be able to move my viewport view, then snap the camera to match that view without having to adjust anything else.  This I can now do now that I know that the zoom amount when in `NUMPAD 0`  camera view is remembered after leaving that view.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First hit <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> to enter camera view, then press <kbd>Home</kbd> so the camera fills the window. (On laptops or smaller keyboards: `View ‣ Cameras ‣ Active Camera` to switch to the camera view, and then `View ‣ Cameras ‣ Frame Camera Bounds` to get the FoV to fill the viewport.)

Now when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> (`View ‣ Align View ‣ Align Active Camera to View`, or go to the camera view any other way) the camera will fill the screen.

If the camera is still not positing where you want it, then that means you are in Orthographic view. Hit <kbd>NumPad 5</kbd> (`View ‣ Perspective/Orthographic`) to switch to perspective view, and the camera will match your view.

Comment: To make the camera view fit the window press **Home**

Comment: @cegaton excellent tip, will edit answer now.

Comment: is there an option for those of us without a numpad?

Comment: @jozxyqk From [the Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/camera_view.html#frame-camera-bounds), the `Home` key is a shortcut for the submenu option `View ‣ Cameras ‣ Frame Camera Bounds`.

Answer (score 16):

After hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> (and being disappointed by a cropped version of what you were expecting), select the camera (in the outliner panel), press <kbd>G</kbd>, then press the middle mouse button and move your mouse towards you. This will allow you to zoom out the camera little by moving the camera back in the correct direction.

When you are happy with the position, press the left mouse button or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the change.

You can also pan and rotate the camera from this view without having to mess about with the camera object itself. See [Dolly](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html?highlight=dolly#dolly-the-view) in the blender docs.

For a beginner the behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> is really frustrating. It's a "feature" which IMO should be changed to take the camera focal length and the size of the current view into account.

Answer (score 6):

Just select the object you want to view through and needs to be fit in the camera frame. Then go to *View menu > Align View > Align Active Camera to Selected*

Your object is full in camera view and can be rendered in full.

Comment: This does not solve the problem that the question is referring to: "Align Active Camera to Selected" does not mean that the camera view will match the viewport.

Comment: I dont have Numpad, so this was helpfull. first clicking "Align to Viewport" and then "Align to Selected" from the same dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

[image]

and make sure the check the lock "camera to view" box on the right.