# How to make camera copy the current 3d view?

Tags: workflow, camera

Sometimes I find the perfect view by moving the scene with middle mouse button in 3d View. Is there any good way to create a camera based on the actual viewport position, size and rotation?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> works, but is not even close enough to be a good solution in my case.

Comment: You can lock the camera to the view with *3D view > Toolshelf (`N`) > View > Lock Camera to View*, then the camera will stay with you when pressing MMB from inside camera view. Not really sure what you're looking for that Ctrl Alt 0 doesn't do..

Comment: see if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8866/2217) answers your question.

Comment: It's not accurate enough for you, because of the different aspect ratio of the 3d View (something like 4:3) and the camera (16:9) and the focal length, right?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "no." <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> is as close as you're going to get. It's not perfect, but it'll get you pretty close. From there, using gandalf3's recommendation to "Lock Camera to View" is probably the best way to refine it from there.

Comment: Alternatively instead of using "Lock Camera" it's possible to select camera, grab it and immediately press `MMB`. It'll do the same but without tweaking camera settings