# How to match the camera to the current 3d view without the cropping?

Tags: interface, camera

I want to set a camera so what the camera sees is exactly what I see in the viewport.

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd> will move the camera to my 3D Viewport location, but it also severely crops the sides and sometimes does not show all geometry.

3D Viewport:

[image: viewport]

Camera view after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd>:

[image: camera]

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd> crops the camera view, zooms out, and clips off the plane in the background.

How do I make it so that hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad0</kbd> actually sets the camera view to the 3D Viewport view, without distorting it, clipping geometry, or otherwise altering the view?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33191/how-to-make-camera-copy-the-current-3d-view. Also this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8842/is-there-a-way-to-align-camera-to-view-and-fit-the-view. The most easiest way imo is to press `MMB` after aligning camera to view and grabbing it along Z normal until satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Numpad0` and then move the camera back on the Local Z axis (double tap Z for local). You may also want to adjust your clipping on your camera. To do that go to the camera settings in the property panel and move the end distance back until everything is there, i.e. not clipped...

Comment: Why is the camera so zoomed in, though? How can I set it so that it does not zoom in/crop by default?

Comment: I don't know, its not that hard to just move the camera back though. You could try using fly mode, I think its called that anyway, just use `Shift` + `F` then use the wasd keys to move and the mouse to rotate