# How to set a camera to catch the exact same configuration as the 3D viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have seen this answer, [Is there a Way to Align Camera to View and Fit the View?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8842/is-there-a-way-to-align-camera-to-view-and-fit-the-view).

But to me it does not do the job : what I want to do is to capture the exact 3D view as I see it (with its aspect ratio and ortho or perspective) in a camera.

Imagine it as some kind of screen capture of what can be obtained in render mode, but into a camera view so that you can apply the render process.