# Camera to match the current 3D viewport Without using Shortcut Ctrl + Alt + 0

Tags: camera, shortcut

To make the camera to match the current 3D viewport, all the answers/tutorials on the web are using this shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

However, I do not have a Numpad and I'm using Mac and it doesn't seem like that shortcut combo is working.

Is there a way to do that without using the keyboard shortcut? I'm guessing there has to be a matching menu item in the editor.

I'm also simply looking for a menu item without having to 'emulate' the numpad.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121926/1245. You can use search in Blender to find operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try one of those ...

- go to menu *View > Align View > Align Active Camera to View* or
- earch for operator *Align Active Camera to View* or
- add to Favourites by right click on operator > **Add to Quick Favourites** ...
  and in viewport call by <kbd>Q</kbd> or

[image]

- go to *User Preferences > Keymap* and assign new shortcut

Comment: Thank you! When I got to that menu item, it was greyed out which explains why the shortcut wasn't working, but that's a different issue altogether.